# How to set the origin point of each bone differently?

Tags: rigging

I've been changing stuff while i was rigging, after i finished adding stuff i noticed that the single bone wasn't rotating like it was doing before, now every bone have one common origin point and if i try to change it for every single bone it changes for every other bone.[image]

As you can see in the picture the arm bone have the origin in the main bone.
How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, There is only one object origin because it's the origin of your object. It's the 0,0,0 point of reference for all bones inside the armature. All bones share this one origin. It's the ball joint that connects the invisible shoebox with the outside world. In that invisible shoebox lies the armature.

In Object Mode, the whole armature rotates around this.

In Pose Mode, every bone usually rotates around it's own root unless constrained in some way.

You are in Edit Mode where neither necessarily applies. There, stuff rotates around the pivot point. That can be, for example, the center of your selection or, if chosen: the 3D Cursor. It changes violently depending on your settings and your selection.

[image]

That also means you are often not merely rotating, you are rotating and moving bones.

Example: you select an entire bone (orange, Edit Mode) and it rotates around its middle. That's not a rotation, that's moving its tip and root in a circular motion. Tip and root will have changed their coordinates.

You select an entire bone (blue, Pose Mode) and it rotates around its root. This is a true rotation because only the direction in which the bone points has changed.

Tip: use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> with 'Fullscreen' disabled to make screenshots. Without the header or the properties (<kbd>N</kbd>) it's hard to see what you are doing.

I think learning by doing is beginning to reach its limits for you. Flying blind can be tiring. You will run into lots of roadblocks if you keep using Blender without knowing it's fundamental concepts of how it organises its data and its hierarchies.

Make it a sport to read a few pages of documentation every day. Otherwise you keep having blind spots creeping up on you when you need it the least ( :

Comment: Thank you for your tips, they are very appreciated! I'm sorry if I didn't explain it corrextly, so the problem appears in Pose mode, where the root of each bone is located where the origin of the object is

Comment: @HelenT. You're welcome. After all, I wanna see a finished movie with the robot ( :

Comment: Sure thing! :) I don't know if I can post another screenshot in the comments to better explain the problem anyway it appears to be in Pose mode too. Is there a way I can tell Blender where I want the root for each bone?

Comment: @HelenT. You can expand your question as much as you like. Also: the root of each bone is at the root of each bone. Where the thick end of the bone sits is where its pivot point is.

Comment: I'll have to guess, but I think you have set the 3D cursor as pivot point and that's why everything rotates around this artificial point. It probably has nothing to do with any origins.

Comment: Oh God... Thank you so much, I was following this tutorial where I needed to change it and I didn't connected the fact that it was that. Problem solved!

Comment: When I had this issue the reason was that I had my pivot point at "3D cursor" instead of literally any other choice.

Answer (score 2):

My post is very late, but I feel this will help others having the same issue.

At some point, the visual cursor ( where you place the mouse to make edits / changes to the bones' translate, rotate, scale, etc. moved to the on-screen origin 0,0,0. This may have happened as a result of some process in Blender.

In Pose Mode:
Clicking somewhere in your work space and pressing <kbd>.</kbd> will set the on-screen location for editing your object's translate, rotate, etc. This will not change the bone's actual pivot point. Let's say, for example, you want to see you model without the on-screen cursor getting in your way visually. You can move the on-screen cursor as a visual aid ( again by pressing <kbd>.</kbd> ).

Pressing <kbd>,</kbd> will restore the on-screen cursor back to the bone's root on-screen.

Hope this helps.